# A potentially flawed thought experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

If we consider light falling on a surface seperating two media. For instance light falling on a watersurface or a normal glass window. We can exactly say that half of the photons will get transmitted while half will get reflected (ignoring absorption) but we cannot predict the fate of an individual photon.

What if in this scenario we send a beam of 100 photons and observe each one and when 50 have reflected lets say the 98th photon is the 50th to get reflected then can't we with certainty predict the fate of the 99th and 100th photon which is sure to get transmitted?

Comment: If you toss 100 coins, do you expect to get *exactly* 50 heads?

Comment: Yes I understand the point. Specifically is my understanding that this situation is different from the coin tossing situation due to the constraint that exactly half have to be reflected wrong?

Comment: Also does this then mean that if we take lets say a thousand such identical scenarios then the ratio of reflected to transimitted photons will always be very close to 1 since each photon has 50/50 chance while it could be very well that in a particular scnario the number of reflected be more or less than transmitted photons? I am asking this since I had read somewhere that exactly half of the photons will transmit. This was then wrong?

Comment: Yes, that was wrong. It's not *exactly* half. The photons behave like an ideal coin toss. In fact, they do a better job than any real coin. ;)

Comment: How do the photons know you are taking 100 samples, and not 110?

Comment: Yes yes. Its clear to me now. Its sad how I just stuck on the part I read without giving it much thought. Its trivial I realize now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't predict with certainty the fate of the 99th and 100th photon in your experiment. It would be the same if you tossed a coin a hundred times; having obtained 50 tales after the 98th time would not make you sure of obtaining two heads in the last two times. The individual results are all **independent** (the coin does not know how many times you launched it, and your photons do not know what happened to the others)

Comment: So  basically the assumption that exactly half of the intensity gets transmitted while other half is reflected is simply not true?

Comment: It is true at the statistical level. The more photons you throw, the closer and closer the ratio between the reflected ones and the transmitted ones will approach $50\ \%$. In a macroscopic ray of light, there are so insanely many of them that we can safely just state that half of the intensity gets transmitted while other half is reflected